# Cflocation bug / new feature in ColdFusion 9 - URL appending twice

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

When a user logs in and is redirected to a secured page, the url is getting appended twice like a list. This in turn causes a 404.

(example: http://uwf.edu/something.cfm,http://uwf.edu/something.cfm)

Currently, the site has a custom login tag which I am unable to edit as I do not have control over it. (It's just a custom cf tag that allows people to login at the university.)

I have to do additional processing after this tag to verify that they are eligible to login on this particular site. Once they have been verified, they are re-directed to another page with cflocation.

```
    <custom login tag>

    <cfinvoke component="#application.path#cfc/security" method = "constructSession" returnvariable = "status">
     .. params excluded..
    </cfinvoke>

    <cfif status eq 1>
    <cflocation url="#someurl_invalid#" addtoken="no" />
    <cfelse>
    <cflocation url="#someurl#" addtoken="no" />
    </cfif>
```

The custom login tag refreshed the current page already, but I obviously do not want that and thus had used the above method to re-direct. This worked in ColdFusion 8.

I read this article: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2050-Changes-In-CFLocation-OnRequestEnd-Behavior-In-ColdFusion-9-s-Application-cfc.htm

The article gave me some insight as to what is going on...but I am unsure how to fix the issue. 
Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have control over the custom tag, you'll have to work around the issue instead of fixing it.

I would recommend changing the code:

```
<cfif status eq 1>
<cflocation url="#ListFirst(someurl_invalid)#" addtoken="no" />
<cfelse>
<cflocation url="#ListFirst(someurl)#" addtoken="no" />
</cfif>
```

It's not pretty but will work whether the URLs are lists or not.